# .htaccess redirecting index.php to root affects administrator login

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla1.5, backend

I would like to redirect the page www.mysite.com/index.php to www.mysite.com/ to prevent duplicate content issues but that causes the problem that I can't login backend because this redirects http://www.example.com/administrator/index.php to http://www.example.com/administrator/ . I am using the following

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.(html?|php)\ HTTP/     
RewriteRule (([^/]+/)*)index\.(html?|php)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but I have had to comment it out to login. Please can anyone show me where am I going wrong?

*I found a post for a similar but not identical problem suggesting

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator could go in the middle, would that be right? Sorry, new to all this :)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want your enter chain to look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.(html?|php)\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator/
RewriteRule (([^/]+/)*)index\.(html?|php)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You pretty much got it right. Each of the *RewriteCond* conditions are inherently ANDed together and applied to the first *RewriteRule* after them. You can have the two RewriteCond in either order and both must be met in order for the rule to be applied.